# BigQuery create view based on future tables using wildcard expresssion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery, terraform

Using terraform, I'm trying to create a view that is responsible of consolidating multiple system tables into a single 'master' system table, e.g.,

```
system_system1
system_system2
...
```

The following query is used to create the view:

```
SELECT * except(non_shared_cols) FROM `project.dataset.system_*`
```

This works as expected, and downstream components can use the master table to compute metrics. However, most of the tables do not exist at creation time of the view, hence I'm getting the following error:

> project:dataset.system_* does not match any table.

I assumed the view would be resolved at query time, but apparently this is not the case. Is there any other BigQuery concept I could rely on to create this view?

Or is this just some kind of a safety check which I can avoid somehow?

---

I could ofcourse create a 'dummy' table in Terraform, but this seems really tedious as I need to know the shared schema of the BigQuery tables in advance.

Comment: You don't need to know the schema in advance, you can create the placeholder table as an empty table with 1 column or something of the sorts, and then replace the table with the new ones on the write jobs. Your query does SELECT *, the underlying engine won't care about the schema at that point.

Comment: This seems again very tedious still, no? If I understand correctly, you have to overwrite that dummy table somewhere in the future right? The problem is that I have a multi-tenant setup, and that this scenario thus occurs in multiple datasets.

Comment: If you clarify what process creates the tables that are non-existent now, I can give it a thought. 
I am struggling to see the limitation impending you from set up the dummy table and then replacing it when loading the real data. (You don't even have to replace it, your Load job could even update the schema)

Comment: Completely valid point. However, in my case I'm having a couple of streaming Google Dataflow pipelines that determine the schema of these tables. Schema updates are not possible in streaming mode unfortunately. It thus depends on the events received by the tenant which tables are filled, so I can't just pinpoint which pipeline should replace the dummy table.

Comment: It does look like a blocker. Can't think of a workaround at the moment but if something comes to mind will drop you a note here. Following just in case.,

Comment: Currently I did a workaround by inlining the the table wildcard in my queries. Fortunately, this was not a lot of work because I'm using Airflow (composer) to orchestrate query execution (and the table name is injected in the query). Hoping another solution pops up though.

Comment: Can you  create the view after the tables are loaded into BigQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't notice your comment. The tables are created by Dataflow, hence it's impossible to know on advance when these tables are created.